# How to set values in spinner dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

I am working on an android application. I am able to display values from the database into the listview but i want to display them into the spinner instead of listview. Here is  the code which i have written for listview

```
      package com.example.festipedia_logo;

//import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
import com.example.festipedia_logo.details2.LoadAllProducts;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class mainpageact extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
     Button button1;
     Button button4;
     ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;
//      String[] city;
        String loc;
        Spinner spinner;
        String location;
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
        String[] city;
        // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        String az;
        // Creating JSON Parser object
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    EditText b;
//      ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;
    ArrayList<String> productsList;
        // url to get all products list
        private static String url_all_products = "http://192.168.0.104:8080/festipedia/sports.php";
    Button a;

        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "products";
        private static final String TAG_NAME = "eventname";

        // products JSONArray
        JSONArray products = null;
    ListView l;
//  Spinner spinner;

        //String loc;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        //getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.fest);
        //getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.drawable.fest);
        Drawable d=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.a5);
        getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(d);

        setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);
        spinner = (Spinner)this.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);




            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
            productsList = new ArrayList<String>();
        //    productsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            new LoadAllProducts().execute();

            spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) { 
                    location=spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }});
//  View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mainmenu, container, false);
        //Intent in = getIntent();
        //loc = in.getStringExtra("loc");
        Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        //TextView t1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.getlocation);
        //t1.setText(loc);


        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // creating new product in background thread

                /*final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
                ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,new home1() , "Fest Content"); 
                ft.commit();*/

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        MainActivity.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);

                //new CreateNewProduct().execute();
            }
        });
button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // creating new product in background thread
    /*  final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,new testing() , "Fest Content"); 
        ft.commit();*/
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                testing.class);
        // Closing all previous activities
        //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
        //new CreateNewProduct().execute();
    }
});
button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // creating new product in background thread
    /*  final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,new testing() , "Fest Content"); 
        ft.commit();*/


        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                search.class);

        startActivity(i);

    }
});

button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // creating new product in background thread

        /*final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,new home1() , "Fest Content"); 
        ft.commit();*/

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                MainActivity.class);
        // Closing all previous activities
        //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(i);

        //new CreateNewProduct().execute();
    }
}); 

button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // creating new product in background thread

        /*final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame,new home1() , "Fest Content"); 
        ft.commit();*/

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                CopyMainActivity.class);
        // Closing all previous activities
        //i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.putExtra("location", location);

        // starting new activity and expecting some response back
        startActivityForResult(i, 100);
        //startActivity(i);

        //new CreateNewProduct().execute();
    }
}); 

    }
    class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(mainpageact.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading products. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("location", az));

            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        //  Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable

                //      String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    //  city[i] = name;
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                        productsList.add(name);
                        //l.setFilterText(id);
                        // creating new HashMap
                    //  HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    //  map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                //      productsList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
            //      city = new String[] { "Mumbai", "Chennai",
                //  "Dubai"};

    //   adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mainpageact.this, R.layout.list_item, productsList);    

         //ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> 
                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mainpageact.this,R.layout.mainmenu, productsList);
                     spinner.setAdapter(adapter); 
                     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         //spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: where are you adding the spinner in layout/code? what is the issue your facing?

Comment: @Libin Can you please check my edit? I am having error at the end where i am trying to set the adapter.

Comment: Do you expect the item in productsList to the shown in spinner?

Comment: see my answer. You should be good now.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you are not calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` after you have loaded the `Spinner` on `onPostExecute()`. That will tell your adapter that the data of the spinner needs to be refreshed.

So, basically try this:

```
protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */
        //      city = new String[] { "Mumbai", "Chennai",
            //  "Dubai"};

     adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(mainpageact.this, productsList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] {
                TAG_NAME},
        new int[] {  R.id.name });  

     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });


    }
```

**NOTE**: When you set the `spinner` to the `adapter` on your `OnCreate()`, the adapter is `null` at that moment. Try doing it inside the `onPostExecute()`. Also, try to avoid the use of that `Thread` inside the `AsyncTask`. It seems unnecessary, but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

There are three issue in your code.

1) Change the productsList declaration as ArrayList( I don't see any need of having HashMap)

So change this line

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productsList;
```

to

```
ArrayList<String> productsList;
```

and instantiate the productsList as

```
productsList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

2) In doInBackground() add the response string item directly to the productsList.

```
String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
productsList.add(name);
```

3) Now the main issue , change the adapter as

```
 adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item, productsList);
 spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: This is not helping. I am not getting any error but its not displaying value in the spinner.

Comment: Try to make this changes and let me know if not helping you

Comment: I have made changes but values are not added in spinner. Please check my edit.